# How to execute psql command using ansible with variables

Tags: ansible, psql

I am trying to run below task but it gives error.

```
-
  name: Check if Schema exist
  shell: "psql -h {{ dbserver }} -U {{ dbuser } {{ dbname }} -c '\dt' | grep -c public"
  environment:
    PGPASSFILE: "{{ pgpass_file }}"
  register: table_count

-
  name: Check if admin user exists or not
  shell: "psql -h {{ dbserver }} -U {{ dbuser } {{ dbname }} -c 'select count(*) from user where name='adam'' | awk NR==3"
  environment:
    PGPASSFILE: "{{ pgpass_file }}"
  register: admin_count
  when: table_count.stdout != "0"
```

Below is the error I am getting.

```
The offending line appears to be:
      name: Check if Schema exist
      shell: "psql -h {{ dbserver }} -U {{ dbuser } {{ dbname }} -c '\dt' | grep -c public"
                                                                       ^ here
```

Now I can try to replace these variables and use it, it might work, but how do I get this working, I tried -c "\dt" (using '' as escape charater) but that didn't work as well

Comment: Try making `\dt` to `\\dt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually the `"` that (needlessly) wraps your `shell:` scalar, since `\` is [*interpreted* inside of double-quoted scalar values](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.0/#id2586243)

One can see this in action:

```sh
$ printf 'alpha: beta \\dt\n' | yaml2json
{"alpha":"beta \\dt"}
$ printf 'alpha: "beta \\dt"\n' | yaml2json
Error: Cannot parse as YAML (while scanning a double-quoted scalar
  in "<byte string>", line 1, column 8:
    alpha: "beta \dt"
           ^
found unknown escape character 'd'
```

Thus, you have a couple of paths forward:

1. just remove the double quotes, since there's nothing in your `shell:` that needs protection from the yaml parser
2. move the interior `\dt` to a *single quoted* `vars:` and let ansible quote it for you
3. Do what P.... said and take your chances with the "how many backslashes do I need for this?" game

```yaml
  shell: psql -h {{ dbserver }} -U {{ dbuser }} {{ dbname }} -c '\dt' | grep -c public
```

or

```yaml
  shell: psql -h {{ dbserver }} -U {{ dbuser }} {{ dbname }} -c {{ psql_c | quote }} | grep -c public
  vars:
    psql_c: '\dt'
```

You'll almost certainly want to take advantage of that `vars:` trick for the next question you're going to ask about why the `name: Check if admin user exists or not` doesn't do what you expect due to the crazy quoting of your `-c` in that statement, too

```yaml
  shell: "psql -h {{ dbserver }} -U {{ dbuser }} {{ dbname }} -c {{ psql_c | quote }} | awk NR==3"
  vars:
    psql_c: >-
      select count(*) from user where name='adam'
```

---

p.s. I took the liberty of fixing your mismatched mustaches typo in `dbuser }}`, too, while I was at it

Comment: Awesome @mdaniel, you explained it very well and works like a charm, and also i understand the use of quotes, i thought it is used for variable substitution

Comment: Now an unrelated question, if you could answer would really appreciate, having issues these 2 variables table_count and admin_count, now admin_count is undefined as task is skipped because table_count = 0, However the issue is next tasks which i want to run when admin_count = 0, which is undefined. Now i used at the beginning 2 variables table_count and admin_count and assigned them to 0 but these register variables are different i get their value by .stdout which is not there in original variables. Hope i made some sense.

Comment: Please don't use comments to ask new questions, ask a new question, although [`|default`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#default) is likely going to be the answer, as would the advice of "please use the search box" since that question comes up over and over again here